# Mapping C# object to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mapping

I am relatively new to MongoDB. I have an object with the following definition

```
[BsonDiscriminator("user")]
public Class BrdUser
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("username")]
    public string UserNm { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("email")]
    public string EmailAdrs { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    public IList<Question> Questions{ get; set; } //<-- Un sure as to what Bson type should this be
}
```

Where `Questions` is another BsonDocument defined as :

```
[BsonDiscriminator("userques")]
public class Question
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Title{ get; set; }

    [BsonElement("desc")]
    public string Desciption{ get; set; }
}
```

My Question is while mapping, what attribute should I use so that the User object deserializes with the Question objects. There is no `[BsonDocument]` attibute in C# Driver.

Comment: Have you tried to serialize objects? what is result?

Comment: My question was what attribute to give to IList<Question>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure where are you stuck but try:

```
var brdDoc = new BrdUser ();
brdDoc.UserNm = "invisible";
brdDoc.EmailAdrs = "someone@womewhere.com";
brdDoc.Questions = new []{ new Question{ Title = "Q", Desciption = "Question to ask" } };

var bsonDocument = brdDoc.ToBsonDocument ();
var jsonDocument = bsonDocument.ToJson ();

Console.WriteLine (jsonDocument);
```

It will print:

```
{ 
   "_id" : null, 
   "username" : "invisible", 
   "email" : "someone@womewhere.com", 
   "Questions" : [{ "_id" : null, "title" : "Q", "desc" : "Question to ask" }] 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my question is that what will be the Attribute given to Questions list? Will it be [BsonElement] or something else?

Comment: You don't have to use attribute. try as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two worked for me..
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;